# XML tags, properties and their definitions

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, properties, tags

I'm looking for somewhere that has a list of all XML tags, with their properties, and the definitions of those properties (i.e. what they affect/do).

I figured MSDN, W3C, or even here on Stack Overflow would have this somewhere, but I couldn't find it in either place, as well as various others.  And it may be that I'm looking in the wrong spot on these sites or just not searching in the way that would give me what I'm looking for, but I've done all that I know to do.

Are there any links that give a listing of XML tags and their sub-properties/respective definitions?

More specifically, I was given some example XML on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620439/visual-studio-not-recognizing-buildstep) question that I asked previously, and the long and short of it is this: I'm trying to integrate some code metrics software in an automated build in TFS 2010, and I'm really close to doing so--it's just a matter of incorporating the right XML to point to this code metrics software.  But through this whole process I've learned that I have no clue what many of the XML tags/properties are actually doing.  Some of them are self-explanatory, but others not so much.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but are you looking for this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e.aspx ? (Child elements can be found by drilling into the help system)

Comment: @Willem van Rumpt, actually yes, and I know why I couldn't find this before--because I was searching too broadly on these sites, as @lavinio pointed out.  This answers my comment I just left below;  Thank you so much for this link!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no authoritative source of all XML tags.

XML means Extensible Markup Language. It is a way of annotating text so that machines can share information.

There are many (thousands? millions?) of schemas, each of which describes a different vocabulary.

You can talk about the set of allowed elements (tags) and attributes (properties) for a given vocabulary only. For example, Visual Studio stores much of its configuration and project information in XML files, but each type has a different schema, so therefore a different set of tags.

Often in addition to the schema, there is some sort of documentation which explains the usage of the various elements and their attributes.

XML can be used for many purposes; some include programming languages (e.g. [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt)), configuration files, documents (Word, Excel, and Powerpoint files now are all XML files zipped into packages) and log files.

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't realize it was that broad, I just assumed XML was like any other language.  I guess that would explain why I wasn't able to find just a simple page with this info on it then.  So if I'm searching for XML in respect to VS2010, in a C# project, using TFS 2010, I would need to just search for a specific schema according to those specs and I would find the definitions I'm looking for?  Or is it still too broad to even do that?

Comment: Disregard my question above, @Willem van Rumpt just answered that question.  Thank you so much for the clarification in this area though.  Very helpful!

Comment: Also - there's plenty of XML that doesn't have a schema. If it isn't necessary to validate it then there's not much reason to have a schema. You can also roll your own XML - just invent the tags/attributes you'd like to have.

Comment: @James Walford, Thanks for this extra information! I had no idea how much XML actually encompassed!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to integrate some code
>   metrics software in an automated build
>   in TFS 2010, and I'm really close to
>   doing so--it's just a matter of
>   incorporating the right XML to point
>   to this code metrics software

Right, so it's not XML itself you're after, it's the particular schema used by TFS 2010. So you may want the [msbuild documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx). In previous versions of TFS this was also used for the Team Build file, but IIRC the Team Build in TFS2010 is based on Workflow Foundation, so you'd probably be better off using the designer (haven't used it yet, so I can't offer any more help than that).

Comment: Yes, the MSBuild reference ended up being what I needed.  Thank you for your affirmation. I wish I could mark multiple answers as the "accepted," but sadly I can't.  SO should implement some "assisted acceptance" method or something. Definitely a +1 though!

Comment: If Dave's answer is the appropriate answer, you should uncheck the answer for lavino and check the answer for Dave.

Comment: I answered the question he asked. :)