# How to Read CodeAnalysisLog XML File?

Tags: xml, code-analysis, access-denied, ndepend

I'm trying to automatically trigger a code analysis software called NDepend on the postbuild event of an automated build in TFS 2010 (If you'd like more details on this, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620439/tfs-2010-code-metrics-integration-automated-builds-fail-code-metrics-dont-run)).

I added this code in:

```
<Target Name="NDepend"  >
    <PropertyGroup>
      <NDPath>c:\tools\NDepend\NDepend.console.exe</NDPath>
      <NDProject>$(SolutionDir)MyProject.ndproj</NDProject>
      <NDOut>$(TargetDir)NDepend</NDOut>
      <NDIn>$(TargetDir)</NDIn>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec
      Command='"$(NDPath)" "$(NDProject)" /OutDir "$(NDOut)" /InDirs "$(NDIn)"'/>
</Target>
```

Much like I did in one of my attempts previously.  It built fine, no errors, but I didn't see any immediate signs of the NDepend running.  However, on a hunch, I decided to check the drop folder from the automated build and I found some XML files labeled "*blah*.CodeAnalysisLog"  And I didn't recall these being there in previous versions, so I tried to open them, thinking it might be the NDepend analysis.  But when I clicked it, Internet Explorer displayed [as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8o4b.png):

> The XML page cannot be displayed
>
> Cannot view XML input using XSLT style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.
>
> Access is denied.

Has anyone experienced this issue? And if so, what is causing it?  Is it something to do with the NDepend XML I added above?  Or is this error completely unrelated to the NDepend XML I've added?

Comment: @John Saunders - Thanks for editing, my title was messy and needed to be changed, but I'm not positive it's an NDepend log file I'm looking at, which is why I changed the title again.  Also, I don't know why you took out the "thank you" at the end, I was just trying to be polite.

Comment: this is not a discussion forum, it's a Q&A site. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts.

Comment: @John - Wasn't aware "Thank you so much in advance" caused so much "clutter" in the question.  Personally, when I read these answers on here, or on other sites yes, I'm looking for answer y to my question x, but I don't think the polite "please" and "thank you" detract from that question and/or answer.  I was raised to have good manners and I respect those who exhibit those manners, even when it comes to black and white Q&A sites like SO.  Now you're probably going to flag this post or call me out for this comment being a "discussion" not a strict "Q&A" but I felt this needed to be said.

Comment: this isn't the place to discuss it. Go over to meta, and add an answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you're getting is because IE doesn't know how to render the XML. Try opening the blah.CodeAnalysisLog in notepad.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried opening with notepad and it was just a page full of raw XML. This may be the right report, but if it is, I'd like to see it NOT in its raw XML form. It may be the case that this file just isn't what I thought it was, though.