# Open an NDepend Project With An Automated Team Build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild, ndepend

I am trying to automatically open an NDepend Project when the Solution builds in an automated build in TFS2010.

This stems from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620439/tfs-2010-code-metrics-integration-automated-builds-fail-code-metrics-dont-run) previous question.  The aforementioned post is where I tried (and failed) to integrate NDepend's code metrics software with an automated Team Build via messing with the XML of my solution.

I decided since I wasn't getting anywhere in messing with the XML, that I would try a different route.  In another program I have developed, I used

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("blah.txt");
```

to trigger Notepad to run and open the text file "blah.txt."

I figured I could use the same concept to possibly help me with this NDepend integration.  So I researched [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) to see if I can find out more about the Process.Start method.  And using this example

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\\myPath\\myFile.htm");
```

I substituted in my own paths to what I believe should open the project file "myProj.ndproj" inside the VisualNDepend application like this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\tools\\NDepend\\VisualNDepend","C:\\myProj\\myProj.ndproj");
```

I may be taking that example and tweaking it out of context, I'm not sure, but it seemed to me that what I tried should work.  The solution built fine without any errors, but VisualNDepend didn't run.

It finally hit me that I was trying to use this code that would only execute when the program *ran* when I really need it to execute when the program *builds* within TFS and Visual Studio.

I asked my coworkers if they knew of any built-in ways within TFS or VS that would recognize whether or not the solution was being built or not.  And they didn't really know of anything in particular.  I tried "Googling" this topic and couldn't find any information that was useful to me.

Does anyone know of how to accomplish this?  Or am I chasing a lost cause by trying to execute some C# code behind the solution?  In which case, is my best bet trying to tweak the XML like I had previously been attempting?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing a custom build task (or tasks).  You can essentially make the task do anything you'd like -- run a process, spit out results, etc., and it can be invoked directly from your MSBuild script.

I'm not sure if I'm answering your question (or if I even have a grasp on what you're trying to do), but that's probably the area I'd be looking to find my solution.